# How to upgrade to 4.4 from 4.3 (Samsung Galaxy S4, already rooted)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

So for a while I've been getting the update message, and not bothered and now it's getting annoying.

It is rooted to 4.3 currently, but when I click install it just takes me to TWRP (I think that's what is called) and I am not sure where to go from here, if I am even on the right track.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if you're on Stock ROM or Custom ROM. But you mention TWRP, so you're probably using a custom recovery (though not necessarily on a custom ROM). What I would try to do is to push Stock Recovery back into your phone, and try the OTA update again.

If that doesn't work, you can download the Stock 4.4 ROM from [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/), and flash it using Odin. Take note that this will wipe your data.

Comment: I think it's a custom ROM, since on Wanam Xposed I get "Your ROM doesn't seem to be a Samsung ROM". So I guess the Stock 4.4 ROM from sammobile would be the way to go.

Comment: @Chris Yes, that would be it. Wipe phone before flashing stock ROM using Odin.

Comment: Or you could install a custom KK ROM instead if you don't want to go stock. There are some great Tochwiz Roms with Xposed installed, and I'm currently using the Google Edition ROM with Android Runtime (ART) enabled and man is it fast!! It's a big difference from Touchwiz! Just an alternative to stock.  Here is the full guide to unroot/restore stock ROMs: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2265477

Answer (score 1):

Since you talk about updates that take you to TWRP, I assume you're talking about Stock ROM with a custom recovery. If you have a stock ROM, any updates are made through recovery. However, the update is programmed to be installed through the **STOCK RECOVERY**

Therefore, you won't be able to install the update. If you already have a rooted device with custom recovery, why don't you just install a custom ROM from XDA?
Not only will you get updated, you can say goodbye to TouchWiz (yay!)